# BigQuery unnest inner string column from ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, STRING>>

Tags: google-bigquery

I am having trouble creating a reproducible example here, because I'm not quite sure how to create a demo example table with a column of type **ARRAY<STRUCT<year STRING, statCrewShirtNumber STRING>>**. We have the following table:

[image]

And we are simply trying to turn **year** into its own column. We try the obvious:

```
select 
    customValues.year as year
from dataset.our_table
```

and get the error `Cannot access field year on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<year STRING, statCrewShirtNumber STRING>>`. So this is not a basic struct, but a struct inside of an array. How can we create a separate column for `year`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to unnest the array as in example below

```
select customValue.year as year
from `dataset.our_table` t, 
t.customValues as customValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this sample table, I also have a struct in an array as well. You can simply use [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest_and_structs) to have separate columns for each field.

[image]

See query below:

```
SELECT gender FROM `sandbox.test_table`, UNNEST(bikerides)
```

Result:

[image]